# loading multiple sql datatables to a single datatable, all tables share one column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, merge, datatable, dataset

i have the following 3 datatables which share a unique id column

```
table1 columns : [catalogid]  [name] [price]

table2 columns : [catalogid]  [stock]

table3 columns : [catalogid]  [minstock]
```

the reultant datatable shall look like

```
result datatable : [catalogid]  [name] [price] [stock] [minstock]
```

i tried the `Datatable.Merge` methode but it not working fine, it doesnt put the data of the 3 datatables in the same row.

i am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining tables in one query is the kind of set based operation databases are very good at doing for you. If your data source is a SQL query like,

```
SELECT
                [t1].[catalogid]
              , [t1].[name]
              , [t1].[price]
              , [t2].[stock]
              , [t3].[minstock]
    FROM
              [table1] [t1]
        LEFT JOIN
              [table2] [t2]
                ON [t2].[catalogid] = [t1].[catalogid]
        LEFT JOIN
              [table3] [t3]
                ON [t3].[catalogid] = [t1].[catalogid]
```

The server would give you what you want before it returns you the data.

Comment: but how would i do this from my vb.net application, LINQ to SQL maybe?

Comment: There are many tutorials on google but the exact right answer rather depends on the application you are writing and is a very broad question.